# Dynamically change SVG shapes on HTML canvas from JSON in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, svg

**Background:**
I work with some people on an Angular project who requested me to create SVG graphics for them; the SVGs are drawn on an HTML canvas and represent obstacles in space.

The coordinates for the obstacles come from a .json file, for example:

```
"obstacles": [
{
    "y": 0,
    "x": 0,
    "w": 125,
    "h": 700
},
{
    "y": 0,
    "x": 0,
    "w": 500,
    "h": 50
},
```

**Problem:** The graphics look correct if an SVG of a solid color is used, which we do for now, however, I'd like to ask if there is a possibility of creating something like this:

[image: JSON Coordinates]

[image: Desired result]  [image: Problematic result]

Hence, I was wondering, since the diagonal grid of the SVG is bounded by a mask, is there is an elegant way to programmatically change only the bounding shape without distorting the underlying masked grid pattern?
The code for the SVG element seems pretty massive and complex, so I wonder how would one do it.

Here is the source code for it just in case: [SVG Source Code](https://www.paste.org/105455)

I hope what I wrote was understandable, if not, feel free to ask anything,

Thank you very much,

Comment: You'll probably have more luck if you use userSpaceOnUse units throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The masks and filters all reference the `<path>` with `id="path_1"` which is in the definitions (`<defs></defs>`) part of the SVG. You can add any arbitrary path (or rectangle, circle etc) in the definitions section then reference it later. `id="path_1"` is referenced in the `<clip-path>` with `id="mask-1"` as an attribute `xlink:href="#path_1"` of `<use>`. It's also referenced in the `<g>` with `id="Mask"` as an attribute `xlink:href="#path_1"` of the 3 `<use>` elements found there.

Here is an example created from the source code you posted: https://www.paste.org/105489

What I've done is created another path in `<defs></defs>` in place of the path that was there before. I kept the id from the previous path (`path_1`) so I didn't have to change any of the references in the code below it. The result is a new shape that doesn't distort anything.

I would also recommend optimizing paths to fewer decimal points or using primitives like rectangles and circles when serving SVG for web, because it will cut down on your file sizes and render times. I don't have experience with Lunacy but it looks like it's only generating paths and not primitive shapes.

Inkscape is handy for SVG manipulation and proofing. You can create arbitrary shapes in Inkscape, copy directly from the Inkscape XML viewer into your source code (or export and then copy). Inkscape also has options for optimizing, or if you prefer the command line, SVGO works well.